# Is there an offline maps application for Android?

Tags: offline, maps

Google Maps is great, but unless you have an unlimited data plan, it's going to cost a lot downloading all that data all the time.

Do you know of any (preferably free) good offline map application for Android? Ideally one that can do navigation (preferably with voice) and in my location (Sydney, Australia).

Comment: Note: Google now provides offline maps.

Comment: Hmmm... How to use Google Navigator with that option of offline maps?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yah, there is a terrific one, called [Maverick Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codesector.maverick.lite).

Off-road GPS navigator with *OSM, Google and Bing maps*. Support for offline maps & multi-touch. Build-in compass, timer and trip computer. Share your current or planned location. Record and upload tracks to GPSies.com. FourSquare support.

And it's free. the paid version costs about $4

Comment: I've been using AndNav2 with offline maps and using "show trace" to show where I've been.  I tried Maverick the other day and it's so much better.  I migrated all my maps to Maverick format and deleted AndNav.  :D

Comment: Maverick is no longer able to download Google Maps, due to prohibition by Google.  Happened to Mobile Atlas Creator, too (though older versions of each still work...)  Of course the other company's maps don't have nearly as much detail about places. :(

Comment: Oh, [nevermind](http://support.codesector.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/14/1/setting-up-custom-map-servers). ;)

Comment: Hey, it's on Google Play!!! https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codesector.maverick.lite&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5jb2Rlc2VjdG9yLm1hdmVyaWNrLmxpdGUiXQ..

Answer (score 10):

There are quite a few that use openstreetmap data. [This is a review of MapDroyd and BigPlanet](http://joesonic.com/blog/2010/01/02/offline-openstreetmap-for-android-2-alternatives/) and the [openstreetmap wiki has a comparison of android clients](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android) - look in the first column and look for "online + offline".

Comment: OSM data is really crappy in the US compared to Google Maps.  In Europe OSM is much better.

Answer (score 7):

In the near future [Google Maps for Mobile 5.0](http://mashable.com/2010/12/07/google-maps-5/) will be released, whose new features include offline storage of area you visit frequently.

Comment: update: it's been released

Comment: It still can't do offline navigation. It caches the maps, but doesn't plan routes.

Answer (score 5):

There is a hack for Google Maps that allows for cached offline maps.  It can only do navigation in the normal way while connected to the Internet though.

[Brut Google Maps](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=630887)

Answer (score 5):

I like Waze.  It is free, works offline (synchs when you're connected to the internet in some way other than 3G).

Its main advantage is feedback from users.  It provides live traffic updates from other Waze users.

You can find it here:

http://www.waze.com/download/android_download/

Comment: Hummm. Nice to know that Waze can work offline :) But in some way can it save maps from some cities to navigate some days without internet???

Answer (score 2):

You can created offline version of Google Maps with on your PC and use it with RMaps application on Android. Works very well for me.

You can download RMaps from Market: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.robert.maps&hl=en

And here is a guide on creating offline maps: http://xslab.com/2011/03/rmaps-offline-navigation-tool-for-android/

Answer (score 2):

Recently, there is a new option: [Sygic](http://www.sygic.com/en/android). This is one of the most important companies in the development of navigation software for mobiles. TomTom has also announced that will launch an Android application in the next months.

Comment: but paid, or not?

Answer (score 2):

[NavFree](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.navfree.android.OSM.ALL) is free and allows you to download maps for offline navigation.

Comment: I used it, but every time I put it on backgroud it closes so I have to remake my route...

Answer (score 1):

I use [Custom Maps](http://www.custommapsapp.com/) a lot myself, but you need to put a map image on your mobile yourself and match a few points up with Google Maps to make it work off-line. I often grab screenshots off [NZ Topo Map](http://www.topomap.co.nz) for taking bush with me using Custom Maps.

Comment: You wrote the latter app, right? Could you add a disclaimer to the answer? See [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion)

Answer (score 0):

[OsmAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand&hl=en) is free popular Offline maps for Android.

- Unlike other apps, OsmAnd uses Vector based (not pixel) maps, which allows it to have crisp and clear viewing at ANY zoom level.
- Includes POIs (points of interest), so you can search and locate the nearest restaurant, gas station, or recreational park.
- Point to any location on the map and save it as a favorite.
- Offline directional navigation to: POIs, favorites, or road intersections.
- Optional extra app for voice navigation that speaks to you.
- While navigating to a destination, it displays: your speed, remaining distance, and estimated time of arrival.
- Alerts for speed limits and speed cameras.
- Ability to avoid: toll roads, ferries, unpaved roads, motorways.
- Supports Car, Bicycle, and Walking modes.
- Supports dark color night viewing.
- Automatic zoom based on speed.
- Have the map stationary with north up, rotate with the compass, or have it rotate in the direction you are traveling.
- Record (track) a path on the map with GPX routes.
- A [plugin to save where you parked your car](http://osmand.net/en/plugins.html), and alert you when your parking time is about to expire.
- A growing number of free Plugins that are being contributed by the community every day.
- Supports Many languages. Here are just a few: English, Dutch, French, German, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Portuguese, Russian, Vietnamese.

**The best part is OsmAnd is GPL Open Source.**

You can help support this project buy purchasing the [OsmAnd+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand.plus) version. This gives you access to download an unlimited number of maps, and access to Wikipedia sight seeing POIs. This app is well worth over double the price they are asking.

[OsmAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand&hl=en)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A very good navigator is [MapFactor Navigator Free](http://navigatorfree.mapfactor.com/en/). As the name suggests, it's free (as in "free beer", not "free speech") and it uses Open Street Maps (free as in "free speech and beer"), directly downloadable by the application menu.

As of today it's still in beta, but I tried it and it works well, comparable to if not better than Sygic, which I was using before.

[MapFactor Navigator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapfactor.navigator) is on Google play.

[image]