# Android full support offline map

Tags: offline-map

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an offline maps application for Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/is-there-an-offline-maps-application-for-android)

I've been using google offline maps, however there is an issue that we cannot search. Is there any application for Android that gives you full support for offline map, support like searching, GPS or more. I currently have a google nexus 7.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [Locus Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=menion.android.locus.pro). Not sure about the free version, but at least the full version's app decription includes *Search (by adress, coordinates, contact)*. It has full offline maps support (downloable directly from within the app), supports location via network as well as GPS, and comes with a lot of useful addons.

There might be other offline map apps available in the Playstore, so you might want to search there. Also, the [Mapsaurus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapsaurus.apps) app (or its [website](http://www.mapsaurus.com/)) might help you find a similar app.

Comment: about locus pro, does it allows offline postcode searching?

Comment: I never tried. Just bought it today after having used the free version for a while. I very much like the possibility to load complete `.kmz` files for offline use -- so I can prepare my own travel guide, including images. And while on vacation, can add other places, record tracks, and more -- to finally be prepared for a nice travel report :) Navigation etc. are also not a bad thing to have.

Comment: yaa, great, so then I'll be also buying it, i already have some £15 which i obtained when i bought the nexus :)

Comment: Make sure to check out their forum then. Lots of material there to download (like POI archives I described above). Also good manuals, and more. Wiki holds a full documentation, too. Have fun with it! I hope I will have fun with it on my vacation now, too :)